# XAML/C++ Progress Bar

Tags: xaml, c++-cli

I'm a newbie to this whole entire XAML ordeal. I need help. i need to know how to set the progress bar visibility to Collapsed ...basically i want to have the progessbar disappear after i reach my target value... Here is the code:

```
this->ProgressBar1->Value += 1;
//This is the target value
if (this->ProgressBar1->Value == 10)
{
    //this line of code just doesnt work... icannot compile Please help.
    this->ProgressBar1->Visibility = Visibility->Collapsed; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to use the namespace

```
this->ProgressBar1->Visibility = Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Collapsed;
```